# Xamarin MvvmCross 5 - Android nested fragments

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to implement fragments in Xamarin.Android with MvvmCross 5...unfortunately so far I could not find a working example for nested fragments.

Can somebody please post an example?
Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Star Wars Sample](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/StarWarsSample/StarWarsSample.Droid) use fragments for example and in the [Playground Area](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Playground) you can find samples too.